# R: create a data frame containing unique different elements across different columns of another data frame

Tags: r

I think it's more intuitive to show what I want to obtain with the following example.
basically, for any level I want to get a list of all the elements contained in the other 3 columns without repetition.

```
    group1     group2       group3     Level 
    cat         cat          dog        1
    dog         parrot       cat        1
    mouse       dolphin      dolphin    1
    red         blue         blue       2
    green       yellow       green      2
    black       purple       cat        2
```

result I want to obtain:

```
var1        level
cat           1
dog           1
mouse         1
dolphin       1
Parrot        1
red           2
blue          2
green         2
purple        2
cat           2
black         2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to pivot into 'long' format and then get the `distinct` roww

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Level, values_to = 'var1') %>%
    distinct(Level, var1) %>%
    select(var1, level = Level)
```

Comment: it gives me this error "Error in pivot_longer(., cols = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9), value.name = "var1") : unused argument (value.name = "var1")"

Comment: @Carbo Sorry, that. was a typo earlier.   I updated it to `values_to`